# Export two images side by side on header pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, pdf, datatables

I have been using [this plugin](https://datatables.net/) for data table and exporting Excel and PDF files. My problem comes with PDF file export, I want to add two images on header page side by side but the only result that I got is an image in a row and the other on the next line, this is part of my code:

```
                 customize: function (doc) {
                    
                    if (doc) {
                        doc.content.splice(0, 0, [{
                            margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
                            alignment: 'left',
                            image: 'base64_Image',
                            width: 100,
                            height: 40,
                        },{
                            margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
                            alignment: 'right',
                            image: 'base64_Image',
                            width: 100,
                            height: 40,
                        }]);

                        console.log(doc);
                    }
                }
```

and this is the result:

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an image to the header as you want, I suggest you do the following:

- Add `pageMargins` attribute to `doc`
- Use the `header` attribute of `doc` to add an image.

2 images side by side

```
customize: function (doc) {
    doc.pageMargins = [40, 80, 40, 60]
    doc.header = [
        {
            margin: 10,
            columns: [
                {
                    image: 'base64_Image',
                    width: 100,
                    height: 40,
                    padding: 10
                },
                {
                    image: 'base64_Image',
                    width: 100,
                    height: 40,
                }
            ],
            columnGap: 10 // optional space between columns
        },
    ]
    return doc
}
```

If you want an image on the left and an image on the right of the header, you just need to add adjust value of `columns` attribute in `header`. Try like this:

```
customize: function (doc) {
    ...
    doc.header = [
        {
            ...
            columns: [
                {
                    image: imageBase64,
                    width: 100,
                    height: 40,
                    padding: 10
                },
                {
                    width: '*',
                    text: ''
                },
                {
                    image: imageBase64,
                    width: 100,
                    height: 40,
                }
            ],
        },
    ]
}
```

Sample code [here](https://codepen.io/lam-td/pen/OJxvWqY)

Comment: Man, I spent a day and hallf with this and you solved it in minutes, thanks